# Butterknife won't work with Proguard enabled, used recommended proguard rules

Tags: android, proguard, butterknife

I'm used `ButterKnife` and in my release build it always throws a `NullPointerException` on any views associated with `@Bind`.

I have put in recommended settings:

I have used the following settings for Butter knife:

**First Interation**:

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

**Second Iteration:**

```
# Butterknife
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
```

At a loss, I want my code obfuscated with `minifyEnabled` but can't seem to use `ButterKnife` with it.

Anytime I turn off `minifyEnabled` it works fine.

Anyone else have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of butterknife

http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

As mentioned by **Jakewharton**

**Be sure to suppress this lint warning in your build.gradle.**

```
   lintOptions {
      disable 'InvalidPackage'
   }
```

**Some configurations may also require additional exclusions.**

```
   packagingOptions {
     exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
   }
```

then try I hope it will work.

Comment: test proguard setting only with butterknife settings

Comment: Then I run into warnings with my other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

## Retain generated class which implement Unbinder.

-keep public class * implements butterknife.Unbinder { public (**, android.view.View); }

## Prevent obfuscation of types which use ButterKnife annotations since the simple name

## is used to reflectively look up the generated ViewBinding.

-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* ; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* ; }

Butterknife Official proguard-rules.txt file [click hear](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife/proguard-rules.txt)